# Does multiprocessing module fix CPython multi-core usage?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, cpython

In CPython, threading module doesn't utilise multiple cores because it uses global interpreter lock. However I recently found [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html) from standard library which is said to sidestep the GIL. So I think with that module it is possible to utilise multiple core properly in CPython, but I wonder if I'm right.

I need to write an app which requires good utilisation of multiple cores, but it's not that performance critical so I could write it in Python, but I need to know whether this module will allow me to  use multiple cores?

Comment: Note that python GIL does *not* prevent the use of multiple cores. It only prevents running *bytecode* on multiple cores. C extension modules can (and often do) release the GIL and allow execution on multiple cores. Most I/O operations on built-ins already release the GIL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` library uses child processes; these each run in their own Python interpreter.

The OS can and will schedule these process across multiple processes and cores, yes. Because each child process is a separate Python interpreter process, the GIL does not interfere.

Comment: is there any way to share data between the processes created with this module, or I need to use classic interprocess communication like sockets?

Comment: The module provides you with higher-level data structures that underneath use IPC. Use those to share data. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).